# Tic Tac Toe Game error

Tags: java

I coded a tic tac toe game and it compiles and runs well, but if you click on the top left box it automatically says that X Wins [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGaRv.jpg). This is the only sport on the board that does that. Not sure what I did wrong in determining the winner. If you would like to see any more of the code the complete code is [here](http://pastebin.com/WNs6YxrM).

```
        //Determine who won
        if(button1.getText() == button2.getText()
                && button2.getText() == button3.getText()
                && button1.getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button4.getText() == button5.getText()
                    && button5.getText() == button6.getText()
                    && button4.getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button7.getText() == button8.getText()
                    && button8.getText() == button9.getText()
                    && button7.getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }

        else if(button1.getText() == button4.getText()
                    && button4.getText() == button7.getText()
                    && button1.getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button2.getText() == button5.getText()
                    && button5.getText() == button8.getText()
                    && button2.getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button3.getText() == button6.getText()
                        && button6.getText() == button9.getText()
                        && button3.getText() != "")
        {
                win = true;
        }
        else if(button1.getText() == button5.getText()
                    && button5.getText() == button9.getText()
                    && button1.getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button3.getText() == button5.getText()
                    && button5.getText() == button7.getText()
                    && button1.getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else
        {
            win = false;
        }

        if (win == true)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                          letter + " Wins!");
        }
        else if (count == 9 && win == false)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                          "Tie Game!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.equals instead of ==`. Not sure which condition refers to top left box.

Comment: Top left box is button1, I should have made that more clear

Comment: I still say we need a vote-to-close option that's "You don't use == in java to compare Strings".

Answer (score 4):

Don't compare strings using `==` and `!=`. Use `equals()` and `!equals()` instead.

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: alright so it would be something like this then

  if((button1.getText()).equals() (button2.getText())
    && (button2.getText()).equals() (button3.getText())
    && (button1.getText()).!equals() "")
  {
   win = true;
  }